# Sybase query doesn't work in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
DELETE  UserDB..UserAccount
  FROM UserDB..UserAccount A, CustDB..ETS_Profile B  
 WHERE A.UserId = B.User_Id
   and  B.Category = 'Customer'
   AND B.Sub_Category = 'Teir'
   and B.Item_Name = 'CUSTODIAN'
```

The above is a Sybase query which works well. I am creating a handler for UserDB and executing this query in Oracle

In oracle I am getting errors if i give the query as below

```
DELETE UserAccount 
  FROM UserAccount A,CustDB.ETS_Profile B
 where A.UserId = B.User_Id
   and  B.Category = 'Customer'
   and B.Sub_Category = 'Teir'
   and B.Item_Name = 'CUSTODIAN';
```

Comment: some syntax errors here (non-closed string literal, double dots in name resolution…

Comment: .. in Sybase is the way to refer the the table from the DB.But in Oracle I have given only single dot

Answer (score 4):

You should probably formulate the query as below:

```
DELETE FROM UserAccount A
 WHERE EXISTS
       ( SELECT NULL
           FROM CustDB.Ets_Profile B
          WHERE B.user_id = A.UserId
            AND B.Category = 'Customer'
            AND B.Sub_Category = 'Teir'
            AND B.Item_Name = 'CUSTODIAN'
       );
```

Comment: Thanks.What does SELECT NULL imply

Comment: @peter:Thanks for the reply.Can u please explain the query.

Comment: @user472625: when you use `WHERE EXISTS` there is a check for the existence of a row, the contents do not matter. Therefore whatever you SELECT in the subquery doesn't matter, `SELECT NULL` is a common way to do it but you could have used `SELECT B.*` or `SELECT Category, 'hello world', SYSDATE FROM CustDB.Ets_profile B`…